# Javascript appendChild() display extra 2 rows

Tags: javascript, html

I have the Javascript appendChild() method working but it's producing two extra rows. How can I only display only one row when I click submit and display another row when I do another entry?

Below is my Javascript code?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Birth Registration</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function regBirth(){
  var myArray =[
      sFirstName = { },
      sLastName = { },
      dob ={}
    ]
  myArray[0]=document.getElementById('firstname').value;//myArray[0] is for the first item
  document.getElementById('fname').innerHTML = myArray[0];

  myArray[1]=document.getElementById('lastname').value;
  document.getElementById('lname').innerHTML =  myArray[1];//myArray[1] is for the second item

  myArray[2]=document.getElementById('birthDate').value;
  document.getElementById('dob').innerHTML =  myArray[2];//myArray[2] is for the third item

  results = []
  results[0] = myArray.length;
  document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = results[0] -2;

    fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    //Table structure variables
    var tablerow, tdFirstName,tdLastName,tdDateOfBirth;
for (i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
    var iteration = myArray[i];
        tablerow = document.createElement('tr');
        //first table cell
        myArray[0] = document.createElement('td');
        myArray[0].innerHTML = iteration;
        tablerow.appendChild(myArray[0]);

        //Second table cell
        myArray[1] = document.createElement('td');
        myArray[1].innerHTML = iteration[0];
        tablerow.appendChild(myArray[1]);

        //Third table cell 
        myArray[2] = document.createElement('td');
        myArray[2].innerHTML = iteration[2];
        tablerow.appendChild(myArray[2]);

        //Table row close
        fragment.appendChild(tablerow);


  }

document.getElementById("details").appendChild(fragment);



}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Birth Registration</h1>
<hr />
<label>First Name:
  <input type='text' id='firstname'  value='Enter your name Here' />
</label>
<label>Last Name:
  <input type='text' id='lastname'   value='Enter your name Here' />
</label>
 <label for="size_1">D.O.B:</label><input type="date" name="size" id="birthDate" value="dd/mm/yy" />
 <hr />
<table id="details">
  <tr>
  <th>First NameName</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>
  <th>Date of Birth</th>
  </tr>


</table>

<input type='button' onclick='regBirth()' value='Submit'/>
<h4>Statistics</h1>
<hr />
<h5>Total Count:</h5><p id="count"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should this have a *homework* tag? If you want the form controls to behave like a form, you need to put them in a form and give the controls a name (either instead of or in addition to the ID).

Comment: what is problem?everything is ok

Answer (score 1):

Try this : for (i=0;i<1;i++){ //code }

Answer (score 0):

The issue is array length. It takes array length as 3. So that appends extra two rows.
So reduce length to 1.